# Under what circumstances telegram blocks a bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I have a bot that sends messages to it's subscribers.It works fine for some hours but after that it stops working. It does not get any updates from web hook. I know that sometimes it hits the telegram limitation and sends more than one message per second to some users but I'm not sure this is the reason that telegram blocks it for hours or not.
this is what telegram documentation says about hitting the limitation but it dose not mention anything about blocking the bot under this circumstances.

> When sending messages inside a particular chat, avoid sending more
> than one message per second. We may allow short bursts that go over
> this limit, but eventually you'll begin receiving 429 errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up [FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this).

Maximum sending speed is 1 message pre second.

You can ask [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport) to check your bot status

Comment: Don't worry about this warning, you can send messages again not longer than one day